# Custom database table - can't add new row but updating existing row works

Tags: database, ce-1.9.0.1, model

I have created module which add new custom table to database and should store there 3 informations: order, transaction id, status

I made my install script and everything was okay, table is created but the problem is I cant add new row by code to the table. If I create row manually through phpMyAdmin, updating and retrieving data from it works perfect.

Do someone has any idea?

Magento version: 1.9.0.1

Installer code:

```
$this->startSetup();
$installer = $this;
$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('company_module/orders'))
    ->addColumn('order_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false, 'unsigned'=>true, 'primary'=>true, 'identity'=>true
        ), 'Order Id')
    ->addColumn('transaction', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Transaction ID')
    ->addColumn('status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Status')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName($installer->getTable('company_module/orders'),
            array('order_id'),Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX),
            array('order_id'),array('type'=>Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX))
        ->SetComment('Order Id');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$this->endSetup();
```

controller code to test it:

```
public function testAction(){

        //This part of code update row which already exists and works fine when I add row in phpmyadmin
        $order_data = array(
                           'transaction' => 34,
                           'status' => "test3"
                       );
        $model = Mage::getModel('company_module/orders')->load(1)->addData($order_data);
        $model->setId(1)->save();

        //this should insert new row but nothing happens and no errors are showed
        $order_model = array(
            'order_id' => 2,
            'transaction' => 2,
            'status' => "test45"
        );
        Mage::getModel('company_module/orders')->setData($order_model)->save();
   }
```

**EDIT #1**
Well, thanks to Stefan Gregori I realize what terrible thing I have done here. I added additional column with auto increment id and changed order_id column to simple integer column and now everything works fine.

But I still didn't reach what I wanted. Is there any way to set order_id unique value to prevent inserting two rows with the same order_id or I have to check it in the code if order_id already exist and if exist in table, just update the row?

My current code below.

**Installer:**

```
$this->startSetup();
$installer = $this;

$table = $installer->getConnection()
    ->newTable($installer->getTable('company_module/orders'))
    ->addColumn('id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false, 'unsigned'=>true, 'primary'=>true, 'identity'=>true
        ), 'Id')
    ->addColumn('order_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Order Id')
    ->addColumn('transaction', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Transaction ID')
    ->addColumn('status', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR, null, array(
        'nullable'  => false,
        ), 'Status')
    ->addIndex($installer->getIdxName($installer->getTable('company_module/orders'),
            array('id'),Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX),
            array('id'),array('type'=>Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX))
        ->SetComment('Id');
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$this->endSetup();
```

**Controller test function:**

```
public function testAction(){


        //This part of code updates row which already exists
        $order_data = array(
                   'order_id' => 2,
                   'transaction' => 34,
                   'status' => "test3"
                       );
        $model = Mage::getModel('company_module/orders')->load(1)->addData($order_data);
        $model->setId(1)->save();

        //This inserts new row
        $order_model = array(
            'order_id' => '1',
            'transaction' => '2',
            'status' => 'test22',

        );
        $model = Mage::getModel('company_module/orders')->setData($order_model);

       try {
            $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
            echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();   
        }
   }
```

Comment: maybe its a help to look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375986/magento-module-insert-update-delete-select-code

Comment: The funny thing I discovered is that when I remove 'order_id => 2' from $order_model it saves row to the table with order_id = 0.

Overmore I dumped this 2 models before save() action (when order_id is set and when it is not set) and when order_id is set, property of object "protected '_isObjectNew' => boolean false" but when it is not set "protected '_isObjectNew' => boolean true"

Comment: You have to create new updated installation script and mention it in config.xml too

Comment: are you trying to set order_id while order id is automatically created in db like primary and autoincrement? :)

Comment: Piyush, all config files are fine and in the right place ;] I didnt copy whole code of module here because now it is quite big.

@Stefan Gregori thanks for help, you can write you comment as answer because it helped me to resolve the problem and I will accept this ;]

Comment: @Furoris Pls provide your actual solution as an answer to your own question so that everybody else can use it!